# How to write Spark logs to S3 when using Kubernetes (EKS)? Error: Unrecognized option: --spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, kubernetes

I'm trying to submit a Spark job on Kubernetes and write logs to S3. I'm using EKS and Spark client mode

I can write my Spark logs to a local directory, e.g., the below works:

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://<k8s-master>:443 \
--deploy-mode client \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
--conf spark.eventLog.dir=file:/tmp/spark_data \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcav66/spark:spark-gus \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
file:///home/gus/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

I'd like to store the logs in an S3 bucket. Based on the Spark docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#secret-management), I'm trying to pass my AWS Access and Secret keys via `spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.[EnvName]`

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://<k8s-master>:443 \
--deploy-mode client \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
--conf spark.eventLog.dir=s3a://<my-bucket> \
--conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=s3a://<my-bucket> \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=gcav66/spark:spark-gus \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aws-secrets:key \
--spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aws-secrets:secret \
--spark.kubernetes.executor.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aws-secrets:key \
--spark.kubernetes.executor.secretKeyRef.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aws-secrets:secret \
file:///home/gus/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

The error I get is:
`Error: Unrecognized option: --spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

I have both an environment variable `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and I created a Kubernetes secret via `kubectl create secret generic aws-secrets --from-file=aws-access-key --from-file=aws-secret-key`

```
$ kubectl get secret
NAME                                                    TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
aws-secrets                                             Opaque                                2      8h
```

I don't think I have a typo - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the configs with `--conf`:

You do: `--spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aws-secrets:key`

You need: `--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.secretKeyRef.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aws-secrets:key`